# Trying to add to a 2d list, getting IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, index-error

I've written a function that will recursively go through a folder in the directory and add the contents of all .dat files to a two-dimensional list. Each column represents a file with each line on a new row. I'm using for loops to achieve this, but I'm getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range` when it tries to put this information into the list. I've looked at every way of getting this information into the list: appending, inserting and just assigning, but they all come out with similar errors.

```
def initialiseitems():
    items = ([], [])
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Bundles/Items/", topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[1] == ".dat":
                if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[0] != "English":
                    prefile = open(os.path.join(root, name), "r")
                    file = prefile.readlines()
                    for lineNumber in range(0, sum(1 for line in file)):
                        line = file[lineNumber].replace('\n', '')
                        items[count].append(line)
                    count = count+1
    return items
```

It should just put them all in the array. It's evident the method of getting this into the list is wrong. What's the best way to do this? Preferably, with no external libraries. Thanks

Edit: Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kenzi/PycharmProjects/workshophelper/main.py", line 3, in <module>
items = initialisation.initialiseitems()
  File "C:\Users\Kenzi\PycharmProjects\workshophelper\initialisation.py", line 15, in initialiseitems
items[count].append(line)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: It returns the name of the file, excluding extension. There's a lot of English.dat files I don't want, and they're not being touched so it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic problem.

You are incrementing `count = count+1` for any `*.dat`  file that is not `English.dat`

You use `count` to index into `items = ([], [])` which has exactly 2 elements.

The third `*.dat` will create a count of 2 -your indexes are only 0 and 1 --> error.

---

You can simplify your code:

```
def initialiseitems():
    items = ([], [])
    count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Bundles/Items/", topdown=False):
        for name in files: 
            if name.endswith(".dat"):
                if not name.startswith("English"):
                    fullname = os.path.join(root, name)
                    with open(fullname, "r") as f:
                        items[0].append( fullname )
                        items[1].append( [x.strip() for x in f.splitlines()]

    return items
```

This returns a tuple (immutable object that contains 2 lists) - the first list contains the filenames,
the second list the filecontent:

```
(["file1","file2"],[ [ ...content of file 1...],[ ...content of file 2 ...]]
```

The `[ ...content of file 1...]` is a list of lines without `\n` at it's ends.

You can work with the result like so:

```
result = initialiseitems()
for filename,filecontent in zip (result[0],result[1]):
    # filename is a string like "path/path/path/filename"
    # filecontent is a list like [ line1, line2, line3, ...]
```

Comment: Yeah, i just realised that i declared that wrong I managed to fix it by turning `items = ([], [])` into `items = []`, which apparently declared it as a tuple before. (Still unsure what that is) Also, instead of having the for loop to put single variables into `items`, i just appended the whole 1d list i made when i turned the file into a list of lines with `prefile = open(os.path.join(root, name), "r")`. Ill show fully when i edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

`items = ([], [])` was declaring the list a a tuple, and not a list. Don't know what it is, but it doesn't work here. I changed it to `items = []` instead.

Furthermore, the for loops i had setup to put the files into the array was and inefficient. I have already loaded the file into a 1d list by opening it and assigning it to a variable, so appending this 1d variable to `items` is effectively appending the whole column. Also, read Patrick's post - i limited the list i was trying to declare to only two columns/rows. not nice.

The code now looks like:

```
def initialiseitems():
items = []
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Bundles/Items/", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[1] == ".dat":
            if os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[0] != "English":
                prefile = open(os.path.join(root, name), "r")
                file = prefile.readlines()
                items.append(file)
return items
```

Also, thanks Jack for fixing my grammar.

Comment: I fixed your code as well - have a look at my version - you should open files using `with open(filename,mode) as f: f.do_stuff ... ` : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files